# Hanging logging threads

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using asp.net core 2.0.3 with NLog and I have problem with logging (I think) threads that won't go away. I'd appreciate anything (even tips how to debug this) that might help to solve this issue.

**Description:**

After starting an application and ping an endpoint (it seems that it doesn't matter which) new thread is created. After repeating that many times thread count builds up so it looks like those threads are not being killed. On the long run this results in OutOfMemoryException.

**My investigation**

It seems that the problem is related to logging as after attaching to one of the threads callstack shows the following:

```
(...)
0e 000000be`0923e8b0 00007ff9`942921e8 System_Private_CoreLib!System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.WaitUntilCountOrTimeout(Int32, UInt32, System.Threading.CancellationToken)$##60020BD+0x90
0f 000000be`0923e900 00007ff9`355b6d12 System_Private_CoreLib!System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.Wait(Int32, System.Threading.CancellationToken)$##60020BC+0x188
10 000000be`0923e9a0 00007ff9`355b6627 0x00007ff9`355b6d12
11 000000be`0923ea00 00007ff9`a1e29a1f 0x00007ff9`355b6627
12 000000be`0923ea80 00007ff9`a1e29ae6 Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_Console!Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.Internal.ConsoleLoggerProcessor.ProcessLogQueue()$##600004E+0x5f
13 000000be`0923eb20 00007ff9`941bb3ee Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_Console!Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.Internal.ConsoleLoggerProcessor.ProcessLogQueue(System.Object)$##600004F+0x16
14 000000be`0923eb50 00007ff9`94249dc6 System_Private_CoreLib!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)$##6002181+0x6e
15 000000be`0923ebc0 00007ff9`941bb3ee System_Private_CoreLib!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)$##6002297+0x1a6
16 000000be`0923ec60 00007ff9`948c35d3 System_Private_CoreLib!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)$##6002181+0x6em.Object)$##6002181+0x6e
(...)
```

Knowing this I commented out *all* instances of ILogger in my application and everything that has even remote connection to custom logging (i.e. uses `Log` methods). Additionally, I removed all `Log<>` injections to my classes. This did not help. 
After that I changed configuration of logs to :

```
 "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Error",
      "System": "Error",
      "Microsoft": "Error"
    }
  }
```

Which did not help as well hence in desperation I removed any notion of logging from `Startup.cs` - removed `loggerFactory.AddNLog()`, `app.AddNLogWeb()` etc. Unfortunately, this did not solve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by me injecting `IServiceCollection` into service collection on startup (`services.AddSingleton(x => services);`) which caused creating multiple connections to database hence background logging.

Comment: registering IServiceCollection makes absolutely no sense at all. It is only used to collect registration within `ConfigureServices`. One you enter `Configure` method, the `IServiceCollection` is completely useless. Before `Configure` is called the IoC/DI Container will be created with `services.BuildProvider()` and after that registrations cant be changed or added anymore, since the container has already been created. What was it you were trying to achieve?

Comment: @Tseng I'm trying to resolve injected services on runtime. Now, instead injecting `IServiceCollection` I'm injecting `IServiceProvider` and it works perfectly. I do understand now that building new ServiceProdivder on every injection was stupid.